# Close session when logging in on a different device

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the default Membership Provider with FormsAuthentication.

I want to ensure, that a user is only logged in on one device. For example if the user is logged in on his desktop pc, and he logs in on his notebook, the desktop session should be closed.

The problem is, that i haven't found a method to close a specific session or to logout a specific user on all devices. I found a method to log out the current user (on the current device) only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use following trick:

get the device name or IP of user and check if current requesting ip/devicename and latest ip/devicename is same or not, if you found different than the latest, you can close the session for that particular user/device.

Comment: The problem is how to close a specific user session. I don't know how to do that. I can only use FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to logout the current user.

Comment: exactly you call signOut() method. You can customize form authorization such that for every single user he/she can have a single instance/ip.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF might help you